# Calculate water area of SAR images of Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, sar

I use this link to extract surface area of water bodies from SAR images

[Google Earth Engine ROI area falling outside/partial coverage by Sentinel 1 Tile](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/369057/google-earth-engine-roi-area-falling-outside-partial-coverage-by-sentinel-1-tile)

But now I would like to calculate the area of inundated areas and export them to CSV file but when running this code, the Error

> flooded.multiply is not a function

What can I do ?

```
var flooded = S1.select("Water")
Map.addLayer(flooded,
 {min:0, max:1, palette: ['grey', 'blue']},
 'flooded')

var areaImage = flooded.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea())

var area = areaImage.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: aoi.geometry(),
  scale: 10,
  maxPixels: 1e10
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Flooded is still an `imageCollection` so you have to select 1 image out that collection:

```
var areaImage = flooded.first().multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea())
var area = areaImage.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: aoi.geometry(),
  scale: 10,
  maxPixels: 1e10
  })
```

In this example I selected the first image with `first()`, but you can also select different images. I can highly recommend doing some tutorials which cover these basic differences between images and imageCollections:
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/tutorials

Comment: thank you very much  for your response but i would like to calculate the area of imagecollection (timeseries). I click the link but i feel confused because it has many tutorials and i don't know what to do. Could you give some specific information? Thanks you in advance

Comment: Your question was related to resolving the error, which is resolved here. You are now asking something different, which I believe requires you to go through some of the basics of GEE, so probably start at the beginning (in the tutorials). Ultimately you are going to want to build a .mapped() function that iterates over the collection and calculates the area at each step: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/ic_mapping

Answer (score 0):

```
var flooded = S1.select("Water")
var areaImage = flooded.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea())

var area3 = areaImage.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry:  aoi.geometry(),,
  scale: 10,
  maxPixels: 1e10
  })

var flooded_area3 = ee.Number(area3.get('classification')).divide(10000).round();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).